# Is it possible to use scala self types with guice?

Tags: scala, playframework, guice, self-type

I have a controller:

```
class HomeController @Inject() (cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc)with Logging 
{
  this: SecuredActionByToken =>

  def index = CheckedToken{ ...
```

Where `SecuredActionByToken` **`trait`** is using class names `CheckTokenService` to verify that user can run 'index' (we are trying to move from kind of cake pattern to Guice).

Is it possible to inject `CheckTokenService` to `SecuredActionByToken`? Of course, I could inject it to `HomeController` itself and work somehow with it, but I don't really want to push some services to controllers when they don't directly use them.

Comment: You can mix constructor injection and method injection when using Guice, although this makes it harder to write tests if you are creating mocks or creating controller instances manually. So your `SecuredActionByToken` needs to have a `@Inject def setCheckTokenService(cts: CheckTokenService)` that will be called after instantiating the controller. See an example [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/fe0fae19579f5d2e86860adcd2b73f15b20bbec2/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Controller.scala#L170-L198).

Answer (score 0):

i ended up creating my own provider for this bean, this way I can inject service directly to provider and use it in overriden trait method:

```
class HomeControllerFactory @Inject()
  (controllerComponents: ControllerComponents, cts: CheckTokenService, dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)
  extends Provider[HomeController]{
  override def get(): HomeController = {
    new HomeController(controllerComponents) with SecuredActionByToken {
      override def checkTokenService: CheckTokenService = cts
    }
  }
}
```

plus binding:

```
bind(classOf[HomeController]).toProvider(classOf[HomeControllerFactory])
```

I can also test is by creating homeController like this:

```
val testCheckTokenService =...
val homeController = new HomeController(stubControllerComponents()) with SecuredActionByToken {
override def checkTokenService: CheckTokenService = testCheckTokenService....
}
```